# Deploy to multiple servers using load balancer

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have multiple tomcat servers behind the load balancer, how i can get to know to which server the app has been deployed and how to deploy to multiple servers at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Release Pipeline, there are two methods to deploy to multiple servers.

Method 1. As matt said, you could create a Deployment Group first. Then you could create targets for each tomcat server.

You could use the following settings in Release Pipeline to deploy to multiple servers at a time :

1. Add deployment group job in Relase Pipeline.
2. Select Deployment Group and set the `Targets to deploy to in parallel`.

[image]

When you run the Release, you can check the deployment of the app on each server.

Method2: you could create [an agent pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser) and [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) for each tomcat server.

You could use the following settings in Release Pipeline deploy to multiple servers at a time:

1. Select the Agent Job.
2. Choose the custom agent pool and set the `Multi-agent` number.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider leveraging a [deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) and a [deployment agent phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) in the release pipeline for this kind of deployment.

> Deployment groups allow you to:
>
> - Specify the security context and runtime targets for the agents. As you create a deployment group, you add users and give them appropriate
>   permissions to administer, manage, view, and use the group.
> - Let you view live logs for each server as a deployment takes place, and download logs for all servers to track your deployments down to
>   individual machines.
> - Enable you to use machine tags to limit deployment to specific sets of target servers.

If you leverage deployment groups you also have the option to [automatically deploy to new targets that are added.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jul-10-vsts#automatically-deploy-to-new-targets-in-a-deployment-group)